# If conditionals "would seem like you are / were" and more

Tags: conditional-constructions

1. If you had given the answer, you would seem like you are / were on my side.
2. if we were to be chased by mob, so help me, would kill you even you are / were my bestfriend.
3. if I were given a chance to prove that I am / was / were honest, I would still lie.
4. if you could coddle the infection, they can amputate it once.
   (Lyrics from Mama by MCR)

What type of sentence conditional is this? It has simple past in the *if* clause and simple present in the main clause, right?

Comment: Which sentence are you talking about, the fourth?  [There are lots of possibilities](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/316142/2085), but I wouldn't call #4 "past + present".  It's "modal + modal".

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, this doesn't appear like this before. Well, I think I have the answer for the fourth one, it's a zero conditional. "Could" is just used as the softer form of "can." For numbers 1 to 3, the slashes separate the choices I'm confused about to use. 1.) are / were. 2.) are / were. 3.) am / was / were.

Comment: If you're committed to this numbered conditionals thing, should we migrate your question to our site for [ell.se], since that's the only place that sort of nomenclature, faulty as it is, exists?

Comment: Please do, I really need some answers. Thank you for your attention.